# Bitcoin cli Error: too few parameters OS X Big Sur

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I'm running Bitcoin core,I struggled for bitcoin conf file till I found this and this is what I just have in it

server=1
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=1300

I have problem with bitcoin cli. I couldn't find any solution to fix it since I have no idea about coding. This is what I see when I try to run it

"Error: too few parameters [Process completed]"

any idea?
I have been searching for solution! let me know if there is anything missing.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `bitcoin-cli`? "Too few parameters" means that you aren't giving it any options for it to know what to do. Usually this means you failed to provide an actual RPC command that you want to run. If you are trying to get Bitcoin Core running, the command is `bitcoind` not `bitcoin-cli`.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work. I tried help on the wallet counsel, I did as I saw for generateblock and that's what happened. For bitcoind this is what I get Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data director. I'm really confused.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `bitcoin-cli` is for sending specific commands to `bitcoind`. It doesn't have a user interface and isn't interactive. Each command has its own arguments, some have many, some have none at all. So what are you trying to do? Too few parameters means that you aren't providing enough arguments to the command you are using.